# How to restore lost contacts without rooting the phone

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

My phone suddenly began to keep restarting every 10-15 minutes. After a few restart, I noticed that my contacts are gone (most of them were stored on the phone).

I searched for data revocery applications but they seem to work only on a rooted phone.

I wonder, is there a way to restore contacts without rooting the phone? What should I try to get my contacts back?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tired putting the Google account back over the device? I would say your contacts will start appearing automatically after you put the same Google account back.

PS: You can check it by heading over to the [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/) just be sure that you are putting the some Google account which you were using previously.

Comment: I checked the account. In Google Contacts it shows only 2 items... So this is not a viable solution :(

Comment: @Nestor that means its not over their :( now what left for you is getting an Android recivery software like Coolmuster Android SMS+Contacts recovery or Dr Wonderfoneshare like tools to try getting your data back. Lastly but not the least be real quick on this if you want these tools should help you out !

Comment: I tried Wonderfoneshare and Coolmuster, but they found 0 contacts to restore :(

Comment: Well, I somewhere get a weird feeling that it may be overwritten by something else ! :( Did you remember putting storing something over your device after the restarting things happens !

Comment: I don't. It restarted 3 times and I noticed that my call history is empty. After that all my contacts were deleted :( It seems, I lost them for good...

Comment: @Nestor I don't think you are going to get that now ! Hopefully keep your fingers crossed and wait a bit more while for other users to respond on this maybe they have some tricks ... :(

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it seems that there is an application that has ALL my lost contacts... my Hangouts shows all of them.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't restore them from that list. Is there a way to restore them from my Hangouts?